# Check if value exists in Lua table

Tags: json, lua

I am running Lua on ESP8266 Wifi module with NodeMCU firmware. My application is listening on TCP port for JSON requests. When I get the request I parse it using:

```
jsonRequest = json.decode(request)
```

So then I can access desired value with:

```
jsonRequest.object.state
```

Everything works perfectly until I send an invalid JSON (without "object"). When that happens I get this error: ***Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)*** and my program stops with execution.

MY PROBLEM: I would like to check if my table contains that key before accessing, but I can't find a way to do it.

I could do it with ***pairs*** function and loop through all keys and check if there is the right one, but that would require **lots** of code because I have multiple nested objects in my JSON.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check if the table `jsonRequest` contains the key `"object"`, use:

```
if jsonRequest.object ~= nil then
```

If the values stored in the table won't be the boolean value `false`, you can also use:

```
if jsonRequest.object then
```